# How to rewrite an url and load the corresponding laravel's route without redirecting?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite `http://example.com:8/?123&x=abc` to `http://example.com:8/lorem/ipsus/123/abc` without any redirection.

I've already done this rule :

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\d+)&x=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^/?$ lorem/ipsus/%1/%2 [QSD,P]
```

But Laravel  handle the wrong route (`/`).
So I've tried to change routes but it seems that Laravel can't handle query string routes :

```
Route::get('?{key}&x={value}', 'myController@store');
Route::get('{data}', 'myController@store')->where(
[
    'data' => '\?\d+&x=.+'
]);
Route::get('lorem/ipsus/{key}/{value}', 'myController@store');
```

None of them actually work.

This is the laravel .htaccess :

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

And I'm lost... Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Remove the htaccess rewrite rules of your first code. Laravel only works with the redirection to index.php, else it would never reach the index.php.

Comment: But the rule in my first code is the rule I want to work with Laravel. On the virtual host, it's working - and not on the htacces... strange...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to do it by adding my custom rule on the virtual host, not the htaccess, with apache mod proxy (P flag):

```
<VirtualHost *:8>

        [...]

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^8$
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\d+)&x=(.+)$
        RewriteRule ^/?$ lorem/ipsus/%1/%2 [QSD,P]

        <Directory "/var/www">
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```